# SlickUpload asynchronous upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, slickupload

Maybe someone know how to implement asynchronous upload with SlickUpload? Now when I upload several files I get Upload Action executed only when all files are uploaded. I would like to process uploaded file imidiatlly after upload without waiting for all files to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing your own `IUploadStreamProvider` or extending the `FileUploadStreamProvider` and then adding your code inside the the `CloseWriteStream` method.

http://slickupload.com/documentation/server-reference/krystalware-slickupload-storage-fileuploadstreamprovider